# ElectronJS with Sparkle: Can we integrate SPARKLE in electron application? How?

Tags: cocoa, electron, sparkle

**What is Sparkle?**

It is an application updater used by almost all applications on mac e.g VLC. It is open source and made by an APPLE insider. It is easy to use and easier to integrate with apps.

Know More:
https://sparkle-project.org/

**What is ElectronJs?**

ElectroJS provides chromium platform to build the cross-platform desktop application.

Know more: http://electron.atom.io/

**Question**

I want to confirm, is it possible to integrate it in Electron JS apps made for OSX?